# How to multiply numeric array values of similar keys in Php?

Tags: php, arrays, key, matrix-multiplication

```
   $a = array ('x' => 2, 'y' => 3);
   $b = array (          'y' => 2, 'z' => 3);

// $c = $a * $b;
// i would like to have

// $c = array ('x' => 0, 'y' => 6, 'z' => 0);
```

Comment: It sounds like you'd like to do cross products or dot products. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to multiply **any** similar keys together, you will need to get a list of the keys.
[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) would appear to be just the function for that.

```
function foo($a, $b)
{
   foreach(array_keys($a) as $i)
   {
      if(array_key_exists($i, $b){  // exists in a and b
          $result[$i] = $a[$i]*$b[$i];
      }else{  // exists and a but not b
          $result[$i] = 0;
      }
   }
   foreach(array_keys($b) as $i)
   {
      if(not array_key_exists($i, $a){ //exists in b but not i a
          $result[$i] = 0;
      }
   }
   return $result
}
```

This will (hopefully) work for any set of keys you hand in, not just x, y, and z.

Answer (score 1):

You could use array_map and abuse bcmul for this purpose:

```
array_map( 'bcmul', $a, $b ) == $a * $b
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a library or define the cross product yourself:

```
function cross_product($a, $b)
{
  return array( $a['y'] * $b['z'] - $a['z'] * $b['y'], ...
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

After further examination of what you're doing, it looks as though you'd like something along the lines of:

```
function multiply_arr($a, $b)
{
  return array($a['x'] * $b['x'], $a['y'] * $b['y'], $a['z'] * $b['z]);
}
```

again, you'll have to make your own function, and you ought to do some error checking in case a value is undefined.